# iterative method for dense non-symmetric matrix

Tags: cuda, iteration

Can someone recommend a good iterative method that can be used to solve a dense non-symmetric linear system?

From my understanding the bi-conjugate gradient method has an irregular convergence and is unstable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [GMRES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method). It requires storing the intermediate residuals and orthogonalizing against them, so the storage grows with iterations. This way it avoids the problem of CG of accumulating the numerical error with iterations.